# Positive even integers a monoid under addition?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Are the positive even integers a monoid under addition?

I think it is, but my book thinks not.

It seems like it is closed, associative and has $0$ as an identity

Comment: $0$ is not positive.

Comment: Perhaps even positive excludes 0 by definition,

Comment: @Mario tHx that does it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite, however the positive integers $\mathbb{N} ∖ {0}$, form a commutative monoid under multiplication.

Comment: Oh thx that is true. Is there a term for abelian monoid?

Comment: @alec I would just refer to an Abelian Moniod.

Comment: I prefer "commutative monoid", and reserve "Abelian" for commutative groups.

Comment: @MarioCarneiro Yes, you are quite right, I was thinking of the way I term Free Abelian Moniods and my work into constructions in the Grothendieck group.

Comment: So we never uses abelian for monoxide ok

Comment: Sorry phone autoworkers and I can't edit

Comment: I think @MarioCarneiro's point refers to the fact that to construct an Abelian group, one must satisfy the five axioms of an Abelian group. Since a Moniod obeys "fewer" axioms, and the Abelian nature refers to Commutativity, a Commutative Moniod is a more exacting term.

Answer (score 0):

The positive integers form a semigroup with addition though, i.e. "monoid sans identity element". This semigroup is also commutative/abelian. The same observations apply to positive even integers (from your question). In fact, these two semigroups [are isomorphic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semigroup#Homomorphisms_and_congruences). In semigroup theory, some reasonable names for it are *infinite [cyclic/monogeneic semigroup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monogenic_semigroup)*, *[free semigroup](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Free_semigroup) on/with one generator*, and some combinations like *free monogenic/cyclic semigroup*.

Answer (score 0):

The algebraic structure formed by the set of all positive integers (or  positive even integers) under addition is a semigroup but ***not*** a monoid; it has no identity element.

If you are considering 0 as an identity element, that is not the case, as it is not a positive integer.